# Water in the interior of a very large continent

Tags: science-based, geography, weather, alternate-worlds, water

Consider a world that is much larger than Earth, but has Earthlike conditions on the surface. (Including gravity = 1g, by some suitable unobtainium.) Clearly, the surface could be covered in a large number of small continents and oceans, but I'm also interested in the possibility of larger ones.

Consider, specifically, a continent a million miles wide, surrounded on all sides by an ocean a million miles wide. What would conditions be like in the interior of the continent?

An obvious first guess is that nearly all the area of the continent would be far from the ocean and therefore, lacking a source of water, would be bone-dry desert.

On the other hand, thinking about it a bit more, there would surely be *some* water even in the center of the continent, by the second law of thermodynamics. If every water molecule were removed from the interior and dumped into the ocean, this would be a low-entropy state; some water will spontaneously diffuse over the whole area, until a state of maximum entropy is reached. In other words, as you journey from the coast toward the interior, the quantity of water per square mile will decrease for the first few thousand miles, but eventually reach a nonzero floor and stay there. So the second guess is that even the center of the continent will not be absolutely dry.

Then again, even though there is a nonzero quantity of water per square mile, that doesn't necessarily mean liquid water. Third guess: maybe the amount will be small enough that the humidity never approaches one hundred percent, so it all stays as water vapor and there is never any liquid water.

But there is differential heating between night and day, and between rock formations with higher and lower albedo. Wind blows across land of different elevations. Chaotic fluid dynamics applies. There is, in short, still weather. Could the weather ever concentrate water vapor enough to produce occasional rain?

Does it matter if there are some lakes and small seas? Consider a sea one thousand miles wide, in the center of the continent. It seems unlikely that it will matter whether the elevation is equal to the ocean half a million miles away. Either way, the water seems likely to end up scattered in the form of vapor across the whole continent. But then, what distinguishes that case from a much larger sea? If there is a sea half a million miles wide within the continent, that seems obviously likely to persist. What is the important factor distinguishing them?

What is the most effective way to keep a very large continent habitable, without chopping it up into a lot of ordinary continents?

Comment: Look at the large continents on Earth.  In general, there is no lack of water in the interiors of continents.  Where there is a lack, it's mostly explained by atmospheric circulation patterns (e.g. the Sahara & Australia), or by geographic barriers (US Great Basin, South America's Atacama Desert, &c).

Comment: What you are effectively describing is [Pangea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea)

Comment: You are asking several different questions here, supercontinents with oceans tens of thousands of miles wide, inside them are not super continents. I was going to answer but you need three answers not one. You have three distinct questions at the end, please limit yourself to one question.

Comment: I’d just like to point out that not even the sun is a million miles wide, so even if you wave your hands as fast as possible, nobody is going to believe that this planet is habitable, with a gravitational force of 1g, or that at that size it’s not, you know, a star, rather than a planet.

Comment: @HolocronCollector unless it's a shell world suspended by mass driver technology above a black hole. Then you can get a construct with a surface that size that has a surface gravity of about one g.

Comment: @TheMadmanandtheFool The answer in that case is simply pumps and underground piping. Though to distribute water to such a large area at such a large distance and area you would have more pipe than continent, I imagine. You might need so much pipe diameter that it may look more like an underground sea with continental support pillars,

Comment: @DKNyugen I'm lost. The mass driver technology implies contained magnetic dust. It seems like hoses would be a really awful way to do that. Friction for one would be a massive problem. A really massive one, particularly if you are planning on accelerating the particles to a nontrivial fraction of c, causality, the speed of light if you want to go that large. Shure, you COULD use pipes but the waste heat generated would be massive and it couldn't support something near that scale with regards to the size of the construct involved, never mind the energy involved in the creation of such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that unobtanium and the vast size of your planet leave it simply as a very large Earth with no other side effects.

It might be possible for water to fall as rain even in the centre of your vast super continent under the right conditions. This could happen if the prevailing winds blew across the continent in an area where the humidity was relatively high and the diurnal day night temperature difference was not that high.

Vast quantities of humid area could be transported for hundreds of thousands of miles over long periods, across vast flat plains provided the air temperature never reached the dew point.

If far into the interior of the continent there was a range of mountains the humid air could be pushed up and over the mountains and most importantly cooled. At this point it would rain.

Even if the changing seasons brought a cooler climate before the humid air reached its destination and the rain was deposited onto the vast plain, it would have no-where to flow to and would likely remain in the vicinity as damp ground or swamp until the temperature rose the following year where upon warm winds would evaporate it.

With damp ground and sunshine vegetation might grow all along this vast corridor with rains coming in the winter and the water evaporating in the summer with the humidity always being driven further inland by the prevailing wind.

Comment: I am skeptical about "Vast quantities of humid [air] could be transported for hundreds of thousands of miles", but the other consideration, I believe, is the key here: "it would have no-where to flow". Even if this supercontinent has perfect slopes for rivers to flow, the gradient would be so low that accumulation of water in lakes and swamps would become unavoidable.

Comment: Water that falls as rain doesn't just disappear.  A good portion soaks into the ground and is eventually taken up and transpired back into the atmosphere by plants.  As for runoff, if the landforms are such that rivers can't flow to the sea, it will collect in lakes at the low points of interior basins, and eventually evaporate. In both cases, the water will fall as precipitation somewhere downwind.  See for instance the lakes of the US Great Basin (in particular the Great Salt Lake: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Salt_Lake_effect ), or the Aral & Caspian Seas in Asia.

Comment: @jamesqf there would need to me hundreds of such lakes in a series to get water to the center of this continent, this continent is thousands of times larger than Pangea.

Comment: Vast quantities of moisture can't be transported that far, it will either have to cross dozens of major circulation cells , or hundreds of highs to low altitude circulation turnovers, Aggregate small scale removal will make the air drier than anyplace on earth.

Comment: But what will happen to any moisture that is released from the atmosphere? It will fall to the ground and eventually evaporate again so just causing a delay. All the while more humid air will be flowing in behind it. The net effect is that moisture will penetrate into the interior.

Comment: @John: If you have a continent that large (and you'd need something like a Ringworld for it), you'd HAVE that series of lakes (and inland seas), because you wouldn't have the gradient needed for rivers to flow all the way to the ocean.  But just look at what happens in the real world: why are not the Rocky Mountains as dry as the low parts of the Great Basin?  And why is there progressively more precipitation as you go east from the Rockies?

Comment: @jamesqf because you are getting progressively closer to the source of the water. North America is weird most continents do not have such a sharp elevation change anyway.  Many deserts have areas lower than sea level that are completely dry, low elevation doesn't matter because no moisture makes it to the area. what will happen is all moisture will be expelled from the air long before it makes it even a fraction of the way into the desert. what little does fall never makes it to a river it evaporates. Also by your logic deserts on EARTH should be wet.

Comment: @John: Climatology is not as simple as you seem to think it is.  Take for instance precipitation: would it surprise you to learn that there are large areas of ocean that get much less than other areas?  Take a look at this nice map of rainfall, courtesy of NASA: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/global-maps/TRMM_3B43M  It's also worth looking at the other maps there

Comment: @John: WRT "getting progressively closer to the source of the water", note that some of the driest areas on Earth are right next to the ocean.  The Atacama Desert, the Namib, Baja California... It might be instructive to look at a rainfall map of Mexico: https://geo-mexico.com/?p=9508  Notice how some areas next to the ocean are very dry, others very wet?

Comment: @jamesqf those places are upwind of their respective oceans, water can't migrate against the wind only with it. Your not telling me anything I don't already know, read my answer.  On EARTH the major circulation cells have a huge effect, but the fictional world will function much differently, there dozens of cells need to be crossed or the cell itself needs to cross hundreds of thousands of miles of land, turning over thousands of times or more,  no moisture will make it through this dehydration gauntlet.

Comment: @james  you will note I said source of water, not just water. water travels in known pathways.

Comment: @John: All I can say is that the best evidence we have (that is, Earth) shows that things don't work that way.  Now if you want to figure out how to adapt a climate model to a ringworld, or some other structure that could have continents of that size, I'll be happy to look at the results.  Heck, here's a link to a climate model of Pangaea: https://www.earthbyte.org/modelling-global-precipitation-since-250-million-years-ago/ There are both deserts and rainy areas in the interior, which seem to be driven more by global circulation than distance from ocean.

Comment: @jamesqf do you not get that global circulation is effected by distance, The Hadley cell cant bring moist air across half a million wiles of deserts, Cells loose water as they travel over land, even with earth distances the effect is noticeable, if they have to travel over half a million miles of land there will be no moisture left. To answer this question you can use earth models but you have to understand how the drastically different scale comes into play. you can't just look at a picture of a model ands assume it scales across several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @jamesqf On earth a major circulation cell will turn over once at most on any continent on earth, on this fictional world is is turning over hundreds if not thousands of times. And that is assuming you still have normal circulation on a a continent of this scale.

Comment: @John, assuming there are at least some Hadley cells that circle the globe regardless of their total number, what about prevailing winds blowing east or west? What happens to the humid air that is continually being blown across the continent? If the ground is flat and there is no way for water to return to the ocean what happens to it?

Comment: @Slarty prevailing winds are the circulation cells I was talking about, wind does not blow linearly in such cells it is a spiral circulation, on the side were the air is moving upwards it dumps moisture creating wet bands, but it is then dry on the downward side, which creates dry bands. without oceans to replenish the moisture air will go through this cycle hundreds of thousands of times without replenishing moisture. It will be drier than anywhere on earth. It will no longer matter which side of circulation you are on because there is no moisture left to dump.

Comment: @Slarty this may help https://www.seas.harvard.edu/climate/eli/research/equable/hadley.html water is simply left behind, the circulation can only drag it so far inland, There is no humidity left in the air once it goes through that many cycles. the interaction with other circulations means water is exchanged and also moving in the opposite direction, being drawn out of the land. Its not a one way system.

Comment: @John: Strange, then, that here in the US Great Basin we can sometimes get dust from China :-)  But be that as it may, you ate apparently missing an important point. Water does not just disappear.  Assume that it starts at an ocean: it will fall somewhere as rain.  That rain will then evaporate and/or be transpired by plants, will be transported some further distance, then fall as rain again.  The process will repeat, and moisture will "leapfrog" across the continent.

Comment: @jamesqf 1. dust is not water vapor, it does not have the same removal mechanism 2. this world is hundreds of  thousands of times larger than earth. You must have missed the part were i mentioned there are also winds moving moisture in the opposite direction, dropped moisture is not picked up because it is dropped in a different part of the cell than the part that takes up water. by your logic there should not be deserts on earth.

Answer (score 3):

Its worse than you think

First I am only answering your first question, answering all of them would be a treatise on deserts , water cycles, tectonics, and climate.

For context Earth had super continents, Pangea being the most famous. The center was desert because distance itself acts to drain moisture content form air.
You are talking about something *thousands* of times larger. If there is no ocean for millions of miles there will be no water in the center, its too far for it to travel. You would need hundreds of gigantic lakes for the lake effect to even get the center to normal desert dryness.  This is not just a desert it is drier than any earth desert. your inland seas will not stay wet they will evaporate.

Even the planets wind cells are working against you, the wind cells will have turned over (gone through spiral rotation) so many times over this distance that they will act as massive dehydrators removing what little water might be in the air.

Diagrams help here.

[image: ![![![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

On the updraft portion of the spiral the air looses moisture, causing a lot of rain and drying the air, without this water the air on the downdraft side is very dry creating arid lands on earth. But here this cycle is repeated over and over *without* the moisture being replenished in the air, this is normally done by water being picked up from the evaporation oceans. on earth the cycle only turns over once or twice before it is back over ocean. But here that is not the case, so the air gets drier and drier with each step forward in the cycle, over hundreds or thousands of cycles there is nothing left. You may have thousands of miles of lush land before it runs out but by the time you are half a million miles inland there is nothing left. Cells moving in the opposite direction carry water away as fast as it is brought in so there is no long term progression inland.,

The center of this desert will be so dry multicellular life will be impossible, even unicellular life might not work.

Answer (score 1):

The only source for water in the interior of land(of any size) is from water-bearing air crossing the coast heading inland.

Yes, water can evaporate from one part of the land, form clouds, and rain again, but this process only shuffles water from one bit of land to another, it does not add to the sum of water on the land.

So, very simple math:
If the outside edge of a form is proportional to the radius of the form, and the surface area is proportional to the SQUARE of the radius of the form, what happens to the ratio of circumference to surface, as the radius becomes ridonkulously large?

Because the maximum water influx of that piece of land is quite linear related to the coastal line, and the surface over which the water must be distributed is proportional to the surface area.

So absolutely guaranteed, if you indefinitely increase the size of your continent, you indefinitely decrease the total water that enters (measured per surface area).

As for just how dry it would get:
A lot drier than the middle of the Gobi desert.
Even a lot drier than the Atacama desert, with its ~ 1mm of annual rainfall.
Possibly as dry as central antartica, with precipitation of about -1.5mm/year
(ice sublimates faster than it snows there)

Comment: The Atacama desert is dry because of the Andes rain shadow and Antarctica is because of the very low temperature. If warm air is able to transport water inland on a prevailing wind and the surface is flat, what will stop the migration of water inland via the humid air itself and rain/evaporation cycles in the prevailing wind?

Comment: @Slarty the fact that a rain/evaporation cycle *never* picks up all the water it dropped. Each such cycle will carry less water. Sure the first couple are very wet. The next dozen dry out progressively. How wet is the 200th cycle? The 41792043th cycle? Remember that this continent is TWO HUNDRED times as wide as the whole continent of Asia

Comment: If it was just one front or wave of of humid air then you are right and each cycle of evaporation would carry less water towards the centre. But its not just one wave its a prevailing wind blowing more and more humid air into the continent making it progressively wetter progressively further inland.

Comment: @slarty by that theory, no such ting as a desert can possibly exist.

Comment: This thing to keep in mind here are the conditions that cause desert formation. For example air being dried after passing over a mountain range. In this case deserts can and will form. Such a thing is very likely on this super cotenant, but we're looking for a way to prevent that. And a way to prevent that is to have warm damp air blowing across very flat land with mountains only in the centre of the continent. Any precipitation has no where to go and will evaporate, replenishing the humidity in the air. It's not a likely situation, but nether is a million mile wide super continent.

Answer (score 1):

### Frame Challenge: Plate Tectonics

The difference between an Ocean and dry ground more than anything relies on differences in elevation. Achieving these differences mostly comes from plate tectonics.  Every square meter of the Earth's crust has pressure building up under it from the mantel, but that pressure will generally migrate to where the crust is already thin to relieve itself. However, if the distance between two fault lines is too great, then the pressure will build up under a thicker part of the crust until it breaks out forming a new fault line.

This new fault line will push the plates apart creating a new low area for an ocean to form.  So, instead of seeing a world with a million mile super contenant, and a million mile ocean, you will more likely see a world with continental shelves and oceans of similar size to those we have had on Earth, but a lot more of them.

Pangea lasted about 100 million years because Earth is small enough to let it come together before new conditions forced it apart, but on a world of the size you are discussing, you will never see all of the continents able to come together before pressure starts breaking them up again.

[image]